# Query By Set in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table of conversations, table of conversations_owned, and a table of player.  I want to find one and only one conversation_owned for any set (meaning distinct group, without respect to ordering) of player.

**converation_owned columns conversation_id and player_id are foreign keys**

```
    CREATE TABLE conversation
(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    created_at TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,
    modified_at TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,
    count INTEGER
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX conversation_id_uindex ON conversation (id);

CREATE TABLE conversation_owned
(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    conversation_id BIGINT DEFAULT nextval('conversation_owned_conversation_id_seq'::regclass) NOT NULL,
    player_id INTEGER,
    created_at TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,
    modified_at TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,
    CONSTRAINT conversation_owned_conversation_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (conversation_id) REFERENCES conversation (id),
    CONSTRAINT conversation_owned_player_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (player_id) REFERENCES 
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX conversation_owned_id_uindex ON conversation_owned (id);

CREATE TABLE player
(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    player_name TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

For example: if I type several contacts (Billy, Joe, and Sue) into iMessage or Facebook Messenger compose window the app will retrieve any existing conversation I have with myself, Billy, Joe, or Sue, regardless of the order I entered them.  But I may have a different conversation that pops up if I enter just Billy and Joe (and not Sue).  I'm looking for a query that can give me this kind of behavior in a relatively efficient way.

Note that if I add a "count" column to the conversation table that has the number of participants in the conversation so that it looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE conversation
    (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
    );
```

I can use this query to get what I want, however it seems to me that I should be able to do this without adding and maintaining a "count" column in conversations!

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  conversation_owned
  INNER JOIN conversation ON conversation_owned.conversation_id=conversation.id
WHERE
  conversation_id
  NOT IN (
    SELECT
      conversation_owned.conversation_id
    FROM
      conversation_owned
    WHERE
      conversation_owned.player_id
    NOT IN (${playerIDs})
  )
AND
    conversation.count = ${participantCount}
AND
  conversation_owned.player_id = ${requestingPlayerID};
```

Comment: [edit] your question and add the `create table` statements for the tables in question, some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [_Formatted_](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) **text** please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name added, thanks!

Comment: looks like `conversation_owned` is a bridge table. It might need foreign keys to player and conversation. Plus: maybe an extra timestamp field. And it will desparately need a primary key, too.

Comment: @wildplasser indeed conversation_owned is a bridge table.  conversation_id and player_id are foreign keys, id is a primary key.  The real table has other columns too but  I did not include them as they do not add any insight into answering my question.

Comment: `conversation_id and player_id are foreign keys` No they are not. Please add the *real* DDL. BTW: this starts to look like a relational-division kind of problem.

Comment: @wildplasser you're right, i over-simplified it.  re-added full ddl.  also added a query below which i know isn't great and uses a `count` field i put in the conversation column...  any thoughts on how to make this more elegant / work without the count?

Comment: BTW: in Postgres, you don't need `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX conversation_owned_id_uindex ON conversation_owned (id);` : a primary key constraint will automagically introduce an index. (The FK fields **will** in practice need supporting indexes, though) BTW2: your junction table could have too many candidate keys. (and the surrogate key is possibly not needed)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126276/discussion-between-antman-and-wildplasser).